# How set auto Thumbnails for video uploaded by api vimeo

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

I use official library for upload and auth in Vimeo: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

I don't know, how to set auto image or custom image for uploaded video by API Vimeo. Please help me by usefull example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Official php library has an undocumented uploadImage method here: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/blob/master/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php#L433 that follow the image upload workflow described here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/pictures

Note that the PHP method takes a `pictures_uri` as the first paramter. This uri can be generated via any picture containing resource (such as videos). The uri is located in the resource representation under `metadata.connections.pictures.uri`.

For example:

`GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/12345`

```
{
    ...,
    "metadata": {
        "connections": {
            "pictures": {
                "uri": "",
                ...,
            }
        }
    }
}
```